# How can I tell whether the windshield and side windows are UV protecting?

Tags: windshield, window

How can I tell whether the windshield and side windows of a car are UV protecting?

I know I could use a [portable UV radiometer/sensor](https://www.google.com/search?q=Portable+UV+Radiometer+and+Sensor), assuming I can place the car under the sun. What are other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [UV ray light](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=UV+ray+light). Keep phosphorus material inside see if it lights up.

Light on the outside, glowing material inside, through the window you hope it does not light up.

Comment: Canadian 20 dollar bill lights up under a UV light.

Comment: Thanks. Aside from the bill, any idea where I could get some cheap phosphorus material?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt anything washed in "whiter than white" washing powder fluoresces under UV.

Comment: You get either 'Tonic Water' or 'Green Anti-Freeze' (old batches used to glow under black UV).

Comment: Most colored price stickers are UV-reactive, as are safety vests, brightly-colored childrens' toys, some white paper, and various other things.  Glow-in-the-dark materials *really* light up under UV.

Comment: How did the test go? Share the results with us. Let us see the glow in the dark scene

Answer (score 2):

According to [this website](http://www.skincancer.org/prevention/are-you-at-risk/sun-hazards-in-your-car) there are two different types of UV radiation, UVA (longwave) and UVB (shortwave). Glass in and of itself absorbs the UVB light. The front windshield is treated to absorb UVA light as well. The sides and back window **are not treated** to absorb UVA light and will allow it to pass through. Unless UVA absorbing tint has been applied to your side/rear windows, the light will pass through.

[image]

Comment: thanks! Is there any way to tell whether UVA absorbing tint has been applied to the side/rear windows?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - You can tell on the glass itself. Look at the edge as the tint will not go *all the way to the edge*. There will be a gap and you'll be able to see it. It's applied to the inside of the window.